# Print contents of array as string

Tags: arrays, c

I have a little function that I am trying to write that takes integer data and converts it to hex values inside char array.

What I want to do is :

1. Take the int array data
2. Convert it to hex inside another array
3. Convert contents of hex array to string
4. Print contents of the string

```c++
int main()
{
    int data[4096];
    char hexString[255];
    char* blah;

    data[0] = 1;
    data[1] = 2;
    data[2] = 3;
    data[3] = 4;
    data[4] = 5;
    data[5] = 6;
    data[6] = 7;
    data[7] = 8;
    data[8] = 9;
    data[9] = 89778116;

    for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        sprintf(&hexString[i], "%02x", data[i]);
        printf("%i %i %s\n", i, data[i], &hexString[i]);
        if(data[i] == NULL) {break;}
    }   

    // print contents of hexString as a single string here

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: please clarify if it is OK to just do step 4 without step 3  , or whether you need to have the full output kept in memory for some other purpose

Comment: You can improve this question by making clear what it is that you do not understand. “Fix my code” by itself is not a very good question. See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` can't represent the same amount of values as an `int`.

Usually the `sizeof(int) == 4 * sizeof(char)`. So, if you wanted to save them in a char array, you would need 2 dimensions.

```
char hexString[4096][10];
// 2 ^ 32 => 9ba461594 in hex, so you need a 10th space for the '\0'

sprintf(&hexString[i], "%02x", data[i]);
```

The way you coded you had a single array and kept overwriting after each iteration:

```
after iter 1: hexString = {'0', '1', '\0', ...}
after iter 2: hexString = {'0', '0', '2', '\0', ...}
after iter 3: hexString = {'0', '0', '0', '3', '\0', ...}
```

And you kept moving the start of the string, printing from it starting from position 0, 1, 2...

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(void)
{
    int data[4096];
    char hexString[255];
    int pos = 0;

    data[0] = 1;
    data[1] = 2;
    data[2] = 3;
    data[3] = 4;
    data[4] = 5;
    data[5] = 6;
    data[6] = 7;
    data[7] = 8;
    data[8] = 9;
    data[9] = 89778116;
    data[10] = 0xf;
    data[11] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        if(data[i] == 0) {break;}
        pos += sprintf(hexString + pos, "%02x", data[i]);
        printf("%i %i %s\n", i, data[i], hexString);
    }   

    // print contents of hexString as a single string here

    return 1;
}
```